# What is the performance overhead of std::mem_fn?

Tags: c++, performance

What is the performance overhead of calling a `std::mem_fn` vs. a raw call to the wrapped member function? I expect that with an optimizing compiler it would be zero since there's probably polymorphic mechanics as there are in `std::function`, but I'm not sure since I don't really know the internals.

Comment: Why you do not create the simplest example with two implementations and not compare it on https://godbolt.org? You could compare it for 32 and 64 bits, for msvc, clang and GCC.

Comment: IIRC it was deprecated. Are lambdas unfit for your purposes?

Comment: @S.M. It's a good idea. I would still be interested in an answer from someone who does know the internals of `mem_fn` and has experience with real-life performance implications of using it.

Comment: @Incomputable It's a general question to understand `std::mem_fn` better as a tool. But for a concrete example, to store lambdas in a data member you would usually need to use `std::function` which does incur a performance penalty, whereas if your generic code would only store functions and member functions you might stumble into using `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: @Incomputable I also don't see notes about it being deprecated (perhaps you mean `std::mem_fun`)

Comment: [Seems easy enough](https://godbolt.org/g/8Aug3V).
TLDR: no overhead on gcc, lots of overhead on MSVC.

Comment: I used the wrong /O flag for MSVC. Check [this](https://godbolt.org/g/e5XX47). No penalty on MSVC either.